# antonym for beneficiary

Tags: antonyms

Is there an antonym for beneficiary that is not simply "giver" or "payer"? I'm looking for a word that roughly mean someone who loses financially in the case of an event.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Please specify that more clearly, describe a situation, and if possible an example sentence in which you want to use the word. One possibility would be **deceased** since that is where the money comes from that the _beneficiaries_ of a will will receive. It could also be **insurance (company)** in the case of the beneficiaries of an insurance policy.

Comment: Are you looking for someone who is financially *liable*?

Comment: ..........loser

Comment: Maybe _victim_?

Comment: @Alo No, not exactly. Maybe an example will help: 

One who receives government assistance is a beneficiary of the government's tax policy. One who pays taxes (and has no choice in whether to do so) is a _____________ .       

Not trying to make a point with the example, really just reaching to find something analogous to my problem.

Comment: @gwatson **Contributor**, an alternative in an answer below, fits your example, and is used commonly to refer to people who pay compulsory taxes.

Comment: What is confusing is that you accepted an answer of which you say in a comment it is not the correct answer...

Comment: @oerkelens fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Obligor" seems to capture the sense you are looking for.

From [Oxford Online:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obligor?q=Obligor)

> A person who owes or undertakes an obligation to another by contract or other legal procedure

An example from [The Code of Federal Regulations of the United States of America, $364.7(c):](https://books.google.com/books?id=xfQ4AAAAIAAJ)

> Settlements may not be approved as to one joint obligor unless approved as to all obligors, including any other persons who may have previously assumed the debt.

Answer (score 6):

From Oxford Advance Learner's Dictionary

> **benefactor**
>   /'be-nə-ˌfak-tər/
>   (noun)
>   *(formal)*
>
> a person who gives money or other help to a person or an organization such as a school or charity:

example

> friends and benefactors of the hospital

**Benefactor** sounds like the best word if you are looking for a word with the same root as beneficiary. In other contexts, you can use **donor**, **contributor**, or even **sponsor**.

Comment: A benefactor _gives_ money, that is not really "losing money in case of an event". Well, it is, but when I give you a present, it's bad form to later complain that _I_ lost it...

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question correctly. It appeared that you were looking for a good synonym for giver or payer.

Comment: I wasn't looking, actually :)

Comment: Yes, I agree that benefactor is a good answer. I should have included it in my exclusion list above. It really doesn't have the connotation I want. I've included a (very rough) example in the comments above. @Always Asking

Answer (score 1):

If you (or anyone else) had in mind 'beneficiary' as someone who is the recipient of beneficence - a kindness perhaps not anticipated - then indeed there does not seem to be an antonym. But one might think there OUGHT to be - 'ought' by noting the existence of almost lost words such as maleficial which seems to be an antonym of beneficial. So can I suggest a neologism - maleficiary? Well, I am about to use it and see if the journal editors cry foul!

Ian Shaw

Comment: A neologism is a word; there are those who feel the need to distinguish between any assemblage of letters someone thinks it a good idea to unleash on the unsuspecting public and one that has been recently accepted into the English lexicon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any standard or legal usage here, but how about (the) disadvantaged ?   E.G.:

> The beneficiaries of the Affordable Care Act gain in large part at the expense of  the (financially) **disadvantaged**; those who had to pay a higher premium than they otherwise would have before the implementation of the ACT.

(plenty of serviceable synonyms, especially with the use of "financially" before :  the  burdened, deprived, even shorn...) The only questions are which are formally accepted as nouns, and what connotation are you shooting for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to find a noun that satisfies your requirement, but there are several adjectives that describe such a person.

They could be *accountable* or *liable*, for instance, even if they aren't personally *responsible*, *guilty* or *culpable* of having caused the event.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. There has to be a german noun that means what I mean, right? I think I'm going to go with "unintentional benfactor"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example:

Two parties commit fraud on behalf of their companies. One company is the beneficiary and the other is the... ?

Victim is the closest of all the words given above, but I wouldn't say that is the best still because its not like that company was entirely innocent. But its also not capturing the whole picture to simply call them the "payer," either.

Answer (score 0):

a *Victim* is maybe your best antonym to Beneficiary (at least that I could think of)

Comment: Hi, Danya. I think that the poster isn't looking for a true antonym of _beneficiary_ (as you suggest, _victim_ would make a pretty good opposite of that word), but a counterpart to _beneficiary_. I get that impression from the poster's talking about _giver_ and _payer_ as terms similar to the one he's looking for. In that case, _benefactor_ is the obvious counterpart—and presumably the word that he was looking for.